# simple range copy issue

Tags: excel, vba

I know I'm being dense but I can't for the life of me find the right syntax for a simple (clipboard free) copy action:

```
Sheets("B").Range(Cells(X, Y), Cells(X, Y+ 3)).value = _
Sheets("A").Range(Cells(1, Z), Cells(1, Z+ 3)).value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to qualify one or both of the uses of `Cells` so that VBA knows what sheet contains those cells:

```
Sheets("B").Range(Sheets("B").Cells(X, Y), Sheets("B").Cells(X, Y+ 3)).Value = _
Sheets("A").Range(Sheets("A").Cells(1, Z), Sheets("A").Cells(1, Z+ 3)).Value
```

Comment: You beat me by 4 seconds. 8P

Comment: @ScottCraner  It is a rare day when I answer a question faster than you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start from a known reference (like "A1") and use the `.Offset()` and `.Resize()` methods for "selecting" the values you want. This way you are guaranteed to get the same number of rows and columns.

```
Sheets("A").Range("A1").Offset(0,Z-1).Resize(1,3).Value = _ 
  Sheets("B").Range("A1").Offset(X-1,Y-1).Resize(1,3).Value
```

This works best in combination with *named ranges* in the worksheet

```
Sheets("A").Range("TableA").Offset(0,X-1).Resize(n,1).Value = _
  Sheets("B").Range("TableB").Offset(0,Y-1).Resize(n,1).Value
```

for copying `n` rows from `TableB` column# `X` onto `TableA` column# `Y`